# Getting Fatal Error when trying to activate wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Here is the error details I am getting:

Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Warning: require_once(/nas/content/live/makefielddev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-services/classes/class-wc-connect-extension-compatibility.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nas/content/live/makefielddev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-services/woocommerce-services.php on line 37

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/nas/content/live/makefielddev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-services/classes/class-wc-connect-extension-compatibility.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/php:/usr/share/php') in /nas/content/live/makefielddev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-services/woocommerce-services.php on line 37

I know there are other threads for this error, but couldn't find a thread with the "couldn't find a directory" error.  I am not sure where to look or how to fix this...Can someone help?

NOTE: I have already tried a different theme and tried deactivating all plugins...regardless I am still getting this error.

More info: this error is triggered specifically by the WooCommerce Tax and Shipping plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- hi
- This problem occurs because php could not find the
  class-wc-connect-extension-compatibility.php file.
- I'm not aware of your code in the woocommerce-services.php file.I
  suggest a general solution, maybe your problem will be solved

First make sure there is such a file in this path

```
  /nas/content/live/makefielddev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-
- services/classes/class-wc-connect-extension-compatibility.php'
```

Next.
Define the following constants in the woocommerce-services.php file
before writing any code

```
if (!defined('WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_BASENAME')) {

    defined('WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_BASENAME') || define('WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_BASENAME',__DIR__);
}
if (!defined('WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_DIR')) {

    define('WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_DIR', WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_BASENAME);
}
```

constant WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_DIR path keeper for
Your plugin.
Replace the code below with your code in the woocommerce-services.php file on line 37

```
  require_once WOOCOMMERCE_SERVICES_DIR.'/classes/class-wc-connect-extension-compatibility.php';
```